# Screen detection using opencv / Emgucv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, emgucv, image-recognition, pattern-recognition

I'm working on computer screen detection using emgucv (a c# opencv wrapper ).
I want to detect my computer screnn and draw a rectangle on it. 

To help in this process, I used 3 Infrared Leds on the screen of the computer which I detect firtsly and after the detection, I could find the screen areas below those 3 leds.
Here is the results after the detection of the 3 leds.

The 3 red boxes are the detected leds.
[image: Here is the image and description].

 And in general I have something like this
[image: General case]

Does anyone have an idea about how I can proceed to detect the whole screan area ?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion but, if you know for a fact that your computer screen is below your LEDs, you could try using OpenCV [GrabCut algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html). Draw a rectangle below the LEDs, large enough to contain the screen (maybe you could guess the size from the space between the LEDs) and use it to initialize the GrabCut.

Let me know what kind of results you get.

Comment: Actually, I'm develooping a real time application, thus I could not use the GrabCut algorithm because of the minimal user interaction required. Do you guys have any idea ?

Comment: I didn't mean to ask the user to draw a Rectangle. You could compute the rectangle automatically so that it includes a large region below the LEDs and see what the GrabCut outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a camera with no IR filter(This is mostly all night vision cameras) so that you can get a more intense light from the LEDs hence making it stand out than what your display would have then its a simple blob detection to get there position.

Another solution would be using ARUCO markers on the display if the view angle you are tending to use are not very large then its should be a compelling option and even the relative position of the camera with the display can be predicted also if that is what you want. With the detection of ARUCO you can get the angles that the plane of the display is placed at hence making the estimation of the display area with them.

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sV7vOTvUCx8] You can take reference from the video and see how he does it in his video - series also